# Subview notifying superview of property change

Tags: swift, uiview

So I have a custom subclass of `UIView` that counts the amount of touches on it and stores it in a property. Lets call it `touchableView`

`touchableView` is in a superview that has a label for displaying that number. 
I can access `touchableView`'s property fine, but how do I know when it has changed?

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: What is the amount of touches?  Pardon me, but that's a bizarre expression.  Is is the number of touches?  Or is it the position of the view where the user has touched?

Comment: That's the amount of current simultaneously touches on the UIView. Calculated using touchesBegan an touchesEnded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with [Taras Chernyshenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4208130/taras-chernyshenko) that the delegate pattern is appropriate for this situation and I have created an example in code:

---

#### Example:

Assuming, your custom subclass of `UIView` is called `CustomView`. We have the following code in the `CustomView.swift` file:

```
protocol CustomViewDelegate: class {
    
    func touchableViewDidStartChange(_ customView: CustomView)
    func touchableViewDidEndChange(_ customView: CustomView)
}

class CustomView: UIView {

    private(set) var touchableView: Int = 0
    
    weak var delegate: CustomViewDelegate?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        addGestureRecognizer(
            UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapGestureHandler(_:)))
        )
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
    
    func tapGestureHandler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        delegate?.touchableViewDidStartChange(self)
        touchableView += 1
        delegate?.touchableViewDidEndChange(self)
    }
}
```

And here is the code in the `ViewController.swift` file:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomViewDelegate {
    
    private let customView: CustomView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        customView.delegate = self
        customView.center = view.center
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        view.addSubview(customView)
    }
    
    //MARK: Custom View delegate methods
    func touchableViewDidStartChange(_ customView: CustomView) {
        print("Touchable View did start change: \(customView.touchableView)")
    }
    
    func touchableViewDidEndChange(_ customView: CustomView) {
        print("Touchable View did end change: \(customView.touchableView)")
    }
}
```

Now, build and run the project. You'll see `touchableViewDidStartChange` and `touchableViewDidEndChange` function will print out the value of the `touchableView` before and after it changes every time you touch the `customView`.

---

It's similar to using `UITextFieldDelegate`, `UITextViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDelegate`, etc, right?

[See here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) for more information about Protocols and Delegates.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [delegate](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/) pattern to achieve it